# Remapping alt+u to get ü on a mac keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, typing

I have a US Keyboard but I often write in German. German only has 4 special characters ä, ö, ü, ß.

Currently, to type an umlaut I have to hold down one of the vowels, wait until a list selection pops up, then press a number to make a selection. This is incredibly annoying.

[image: umlaut description]

[image: umlaut description]

[image: a umlaut description]

[image: o umlaut description]

I found a solution of sorts... this allows you to edit the list selection popup so that only German characters appear. This cuts down on the selection time but it's still cumbersome.

https://weblog.masukomi.org/2015/12/13/esperanto-press-and-hold-characters/

Now I have something that's much nicer, but still cumbersome.

[image: description umlaut]

[image: description umlaut]

[image: description umlaut]

[image: description umlaut]

What I would like is this:

```
`alt/option + u = ü`
```

same for a, o and s.

Is this possible, if so how?

Comment: alt-u then u would do the trick. alt-u then o, alt-u then a. Umlaut is alt-s

Comment: Closer! So close! Definitely the better option to press and hold! But not quite perfect. I want alt-u to give me ü, alt-a to give me ä, alt-o to give me ö the same way that alt-s gives me ß. Make sense?

Comment: Then you have to create your own keyboard layout. There exist some tools for this. I didn't use one since many years (ukulele for example). You can also let the system bind sequences to your needs, for example `"u` for `ü` (use systems preferences - keyboard - text, then add text and replacement.